# paramiko combine stdout and stderr

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to combine the output of stdout and stderr. My belief is that this can be done with the set_combine_stderr() of a Channel object.

This is what I am doing:

```
SSH = paramiko.SSHClient()
#I connect and everything OK, then:
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.set_combine_stderr(True)
chan.exec_command('python2.6 subir.py')
resultado = chan.makefile('rb', -1.)
```

However, I get the following error when I try to store the result (last line above, chan.makefile() ):

> Error: Channel closed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 22):

While it is true that `set_combine_stderr` diverts `stderr` to the `stdout` stream, it does so in chaotic order, so you do not get the result you probably want, namely, the lines combined in the order written, as if you were running the command in a local terminal window. Instead, use `get_pty`. That will cause the server to run the lines through a pseudo-terminal, keeping them in chronological sequence.

Here's a test program, `outerr.py`, that writes alternating lines on `stdout` and `stdin`. Assume it's sitting in the home directory of llmps@meerkat2.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for x in xrange(1, 101):
    (sys.stdout, sys.stderr)[x%2].write('This is line #%s, on std%s.\n' %
                (x, ('out', 'err')[x%2]))
```

Now try the following code to run it remotely:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko

def connect():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('meerkat2', username='llmps', password='..')
    return ssh

def runTest(ssh):
    tran = ssh.get_transport()
    chan = tran.open_session()
    # chan.set_combine_stderr(True)
    chan.get_pty()
    f = chan.makefile()
    chan.exec_command('./outerr.py')
    print f.read(),

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssh = connect()
    runTest(ssh)
    ssh.close()
```

If you run the above, you should see 100 lines in order as written. If, instead, you comment out the `chan.get_pty()` call and uncomment the `chan.set_combine_stderr(True)` call, you will get clumps of `stdout` and `stderr` lines interspersed randomly from run to run.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I know this is quite an old topic, but I run into the same problem and I got a (maybe not-so-)pretty solution. Just call the command on the remote server redirecting the stderr to stdout and then always read from the stdout. For example:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('hostname', username='user', password='pass')

stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('python your_script.py 2> \&1')
print stdout.read()
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! the backslash on `\&1` is what i was missing. why is that needed?

Comment: It has been a while since I wrote this answer. If I remember correctly, you need to escape the '&' char, so bash doesn't interpret it as a signal to run the command in the background.

Answer (score 3):

@AaronMcSmooth: I am referring to the stdout and stderr of the computer I am connecting to (via SSH).

I ended up doing this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(...)

output = stdin.read().strip() + stdout.read().strip()
```

For the purpose of my application, it doesn't matter to distinguish between stdout and stderr, but I don't think that's the best way to combine the two.

The code of `SSHClient.exec_command()` is (looking at paramiko's source code):

```
def exec_command(self, command, bufsize=-1):
    chan = self._transport.open_session() 
    chan.exec_command(command) 
    stdin = chan.makefile('wb', bufsize) 
    stdout = chan.makefile('rb', bufsize) 
    stderr = chan.makefile_stderr('rb', bufsize) 
    return stdin, stdout, stderr
```

I am performing the same actions on the channel but receive the Channel is closed error.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read from `stdin`? I think you may have meant to read from `stderr`.